# How to remove seconds from LastModifiedDate in flow in Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, datetime

I am doing it in Record triggered flow and Trying to compare createddate and lastmodifieddate. when both are equal I'll update the record. Since createddate and lastmodifieddate are standard field so it takes this format (2022-10-18T12:53:52.000+0000) but while comparing I do not want to consider seconds and hence want to remove seconds using formula in Flow.

How to remove seconds from LastModifiedDate in flow in Salesforce.

Comment: Can you please post your flow screenshot as well in the question. Secondly, why would you wanna compare modifieddate with created date? Only instance in normal Salesforce operations when both dates will be equal is insertion of new record. Check answer posted by @roh777x. Checking `isNew()` is way better approach.

Answer (score 1):

From your question

> Trying to compare createddate and lastmodifieddate. when both are equal I'll update the record.

There are other better ways to figure out if the record is being inserted or updated in Flows. `ISNEW()` formula method can help.

Refer this Question : [How to check isInsert or isUpdate in flow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344429/how-to-check-isinsert-or-isupdate-in-flow#:%7E:text=In%20a%20before%2Dsave%20flow,the%20Created%20Date%20was%20changed.)