# In a Decision in a Flow, how can I set a branch for a record that's been created, versus updated?

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere.

I have a Flow that triggers when an Opportunity is created or updated.

I need a Decision with two branches. If the Opportunity has just been created, then it should always then go into an Outbound Message, that sends it to an endpoint on our ETL tool that feeds into our data lake.

But if the Opportunity was just updated, then we only want to send it to the Outbound Message if StageName IsChanged equals true.

But how can I find out if the Opportunity has been created or updated? I can't figure out how to branch on that condition.

If I use the `IsNew()` function, then where do I use it? Do I create a new field on the object?

Comment: Consider the ISNEW function in a formula expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IsChanged Flow Entry Criteria when record is created](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382101/ischanged-flow-entry-criteria-when-record-is-created)

Comment: I tried to create a new formula field on the Opportunity, with the formula being "IsNew()" but I get an error saying " Error: Function ISNEW may not be used in this type of formula". How do I create this field?

Comment: "Consider the ISNEW function in a formula expression" -- but where does this go? Am I creating a new field not the object? I get an error if I try it. I am new to Salesforce, so perhaps I misunderstand you.

Comment: see also - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/344430/2602

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check isInsert or isUpdate in flow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344429/how-to-check-isinsert-or-isupdate-in-flow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a Boolean formula called 'isNew'
2. The formula just needs to be 'ISNEW()'
3. Update your decision to check is 'isNew' is true

voila

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to create a new formula field on the Opportunity, with the formula being "IsNew()" but I get an error saying " Error: Function ISNEW may not be used in this type of formula". How do I create this field?

Comment: "Create a Boolean formula called 'isNew'" -- but where does this go? Am I creating a new field not the object? I get an error if I try it. I am new to Salesforce, so perhaps I misunderstand you.

Comment: @charlottesville This is in the flow itself, not as a field on the record.